# Bootstrap UI Modal - Injecting and initializing $index for ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Currently I have a image gallery like this:

```
        <div class="slider">
            <img ng-repeat="image in gallery" class="img-responsive" ng-swipe-right="showPrev()" ng-swipe-left="showNext()" ng-show="isActive($index)" ng-src="{{image}}" ng-click="open($index)"/>

            <a class="arrow prev" ng-click="showPrev()"></a>
            <a class="arrow next" ng-click="showNext()"></a>

            <ul class="navigator">
                <li ng-repeat="image in gallery" ng-class="{'active':isActive($index)}">
                    <img src="{{image}}" ng-click="showPhoto($index);" class="img-responsive" />
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

My image gallery functions look like this:

```
// initial image index
$scope._Index = 0;

// if a current image is the same as requested image
$scope.isActive = function (index) {
    return $scope._Index === index;
};

// show prev image
$scope.showPrev = function () {
    $scope._Index = ($scope._Index > 0) ? --$scope._Index : $scope.gallery.length - 1;
};

// show next image
$scope.showNext = function () {
    $scope._Index = ($scope._Index < $scope.gallery.length - 1) ? ++$scope._Index : 0;
};

// show a certain image
$scope.showPhoto = function (index) {
    $scope._Index = index;
};
```

When I click on a image my 'open' function will run:

```
$scope.open = function (index) {

  $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'templates/hotelmodal.html',
    controller: 'HotelCtrl',
    size: 'lg',
    scope:$scope

  });

};
```

And a modal will pop-up:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Billedfremviser</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
<div ng-cloak class="slider">
            <img ng-init="$index = 1" ng-repeat="image in gallery" class="img-responsive" ng-swipe-right="showPrev()" ng-swipe-left="showNext()" ng-show="isActive($index)" ng-src="{{image}}"/>

            <a class="arrow prev" ng-click="showPrev()"></a>
            <a class="arrow next" ng-click="showNext()"></a>

            <ul class="navigator">
                <li ng-repeat="image in gallery" ng-class="{'active':isActive($index)}">
                    <img src="{{image}}" ng-click="showPhoto($index);" class="img-responsive" />
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>       
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="close()">Luk billedfremviser</button>
  </div>
```

As you can see my main gallery site and the content of the modal is almost the same.
The only purpose of the modal is to show the image in a larger size - which is working perfectly.
My only problem is, that I want the modal to show the same image as the main gallery site when it opens.

I've tried to use the following on the modal ng-repeat - just for test purpose:

```
ng-init="$index = 1"
```

But it just mess up ng-repeat. 
As you can see I inject $index in my open function - but again.. I don't know how to use the number in the in the modal ng-repeat.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$index` is a built in angular property; you shouldn't need to initialize it.  Also, `$index` is `0` based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing i needed to do was:

```
// initial image index
if (!$scope._Index) {
  $scope._Index = 0;
}
```

Hereafter the $scope._Index im using to determine the active picture, will not be set to 0 when the modal opens with the same controller. The picture will then be the same in the modal as on the main page.

I don't think this is the best way to do it, but it's working great.